# I have a ValueError at /accounts/register/ in registration form

Tags: django, django-views, registration, valueerror

This is a `views.py` that checks the validation of the registration form, but when I register a form in a server I find a **ValueError at /accounts/register/**.

```py
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'

    # display blank form
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
    
    # process form data
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=True)
            
            # cleaned (normalized) data
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            date_of_birth = form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            address = form.cleaned_data['address']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            

            user.set_password(password)

            user.save()

            # returns user objects if credentials are correct

            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('accounts:home')

            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form.as_p})
```

Comment: As you have not shown the error, I can assume that it's coming from one of the line where you are fetching data from `form.cleaned_data`. So basically there is some key that does not exist in cleaned_data, that you strictly accessing. So you can check which one is not in cleaned_data by printing its value or you can use `form.cleaned_data.get('key_name')`

Comment: i tried  this but it doesn't solve error ... @VineetYadav

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you trying to save blank data in your database table. So instead of doing this

```py
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save(commit=True) # this will try to save your data in db
```

try this:

```py
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save(commit=False) # return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database
```

You can read more about **save()** method [here in django's docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)